# Notification System that loops through first ten database entries

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database, dynamic

I have looked for days now and cannot seem to find any direct examples of what I am trying to accomplish, that I can reference.

I am trying to create a simple, elegant notification system, that pulls a persons image, name (in text format), and a predefined message (selected from drop down menu), from a database, and then displays the info in an elegant little "profile like" layout, on a webpage or smartphone. The only feature that I want the app to have is an auto refresh setup (using AJAX maybe?) that cycles through the latest ten entries into the database, in a continual loop.

I already have the MySql database set up, as well as the form which supplies the information that I want show, into the database -- but I can't for the life of me figure out how to pull that info into a nice little alert, and get it to cycle through the latest ten database entries.

Thank you so much, in advance, for any assistance you can provide. I'm ok with databases, and Php, but I'm racking my brain trying to figure out how to get it to display and cycle through the first ten entries.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you have an id column or some sort of timestamp column, you can use ORDER BY and LIMIT in MySql to extract only the last X recrods.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM profiles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

That will extract the top 10 id's, where in a standard id column, that will be the last 10 records.

As for formating the display - that is way to wide, and there are a lot of ways to do so.

Comment: Awesome, that answers one of my questions -- thank you. How do you suppose I'd go about getting the display to cycle through each entry, one at a time, continually? (Imagine the layout of a Pokemon card) The image and "customer" name will replace the info on the card. And a new "card" (or profile, or whatever we'd like to call it) flashes onto the screen, one at a time, in a continual loop, say, every 10 seconds. It cant be much more than some html work and a little bit of AJAX to auto refresh the image and customer name with the info from the next row in the db..no?

Comment: The most important feature is that this app just sits there and cycles through the 10 newest entries into the db, and displays them, one by one, in the form of little "Congratulations!" popups, with the persons name and image.

Comment: Assuming you are not getting 100's of new profiles every couple of minutes, I would suggest an ajax that runs every couple of minutes and fetch the data. To display it, I would use something like a carousel. Look up jQuery carousel in google, you will find tons of implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have PHP file with SQL query `SELECT ... ORDER BY id LIMIT 10`, and use json_encode to JSON encode the returned array. JSON is easy to use with AJAX with JavaScript.
And about AJAX - I would use jQuery and use jQuery.getJson from PHP file do sleep and loop it

EDIT: On refresh you will do a new JSON parse, and remove last elements of container with cards, and use new elements